# Google-Home: NOTIFICATION_ENABLED_BY_USER_FALSE error even if all rights have been enabled

Tags: google-home

In a Google Home Action test app I continue to get error NOTIFICATION_ENABLED_BY_USER_FALSE upon reportStateAndNotification API call (raising a notification).
Except from Google Home App, where all notifications are enabled, is there any other way to verify if notification are really turned on? Any suggestion on how to verify why this error is reported?

Thanks

Comment: NOTIFICATION_ENABLED_BY_USER_FALSE error in a Google Home Action test app, it indicates that the user has not enabled notifications on the notifying device in the Google Home App (GHA). This [status](https://developers.home.google.com/cloud-to-cloud/integration/notifications) is relevant only during testing and is not available once the Actions have been launched to production.